How do we know from the Bible that Adam and Eve have been saved from the lake of fire?
How do we know from the Bible that Adam and Eve have been saved from the lake of fire?
According to my knowledge, it is a fairly unanimous position among the Oriental Christianity, the Roman Catholic Church, the Orthodox Church, and the mainstream Protestantism (I mean those protestants those who directly address Jesus by His name in their prayers) that Adam and Eve are saved and therefore will not go to the lake of fire in future eternity.
Usually, this verse is cited:

"And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy
seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his
heel." (Genesis 3:15, KJV)

However, the language here is rather metaphorical, and to me it looks like an overreach to claim that this verse definitively states that Adam and Eve are saved.
So, has there been any attempt within Christianity—I am sure there has—to provide a logical and exhaustive proof from other parts of Scripture, both the Old Testament and the New Testament, that Adam and Eve are saved from the lake of fire?

We don't. And in my experience protestants are usually agnostic on the question

"it is a fairly unanimous position among the Oriental Christianity, the Roman Catholic Church, the Orthodox Church, and the mainstream Protestantism … that Adam and Eve are saved and therefore will not go to the lake of fire in future eternity." — The question would be improved by including explicit quotations about this from the various denominations.

Enmity between humans and snakes and one trying to hurt the other seems fairly literal language.

@Henry: It is literal as long as you are talking exactly about that - the enmity between humans and snakes, but it is only metaphorical if in those words you see the statment that Adam and Eve are saved.

I could give you some biblical arguments on why one could conclude from the Bible that Adam and Eve are not saved from the lake of fire. I don't know though if that is wanted as an answer here.

If this was rephrased “ how do we know IF” Instead of “ how do we know THAT”   Both pov in answers could be acceptable.

@007 Questions aren't allowed to do both sides, other than in overview questions. This one is better just having the pro case.

@curiousdannii so the answer fro Jswitness is off topic? And Nigel since one answers no and the other answers we don’t know

@007 I haven't looked at the answers, but if they're arguing against Adam and Eve being saved then they would be invalid answers

After God judged Adam for his transgression, cursing the ground (but not cursing humanity) and cursing the serpentine spirit by whom sin came into the world, and after God banished the first man, Adam, from the arena of providential plenitude, requiring him to labour and perspire for his food, rather than receive freely an unearned benefit, after all this, yet God clothed the first man and the first woman in skins.
And Adam responded to this and also responded to the promise which God made, regarding a seed to come, a seed of woman (but not stated to be of man) a seed which from above (that is to say ascended to an elevated position) would bruise the head of the serpentine spirit, this response from Adam being to name his wife 'Eve' the mother of all living, an indication of faith in Adam for he was responding (as Abraham did many centuries later) by faith to a promise made by God.
Abraham believed God and it was accounted to him unto righteousness. And so did Adam, in his day.
Not only so, but later, when Cain 'went out from the presence of the Lord' it was the household of Adam from which he went out. Now, since Adam was banished from Eden the 'presence of the Lord' spoken of by Moses in the Genesis account is not the presence of God in Eden, but is the presence of the Lord within Adam's own household.
Thus I see in this that Adam showed a response of faith to the promise of God and the presence of the Lord was within his household as a result.
More than that, scripture does not say. And I think we have to be careful what wording we use, that we should only state what scripture states and that we should not state matters couched in terms beyond what scripture asserts as this often confuses matters, often preempting that which has not (yet) been revealed.
So, I am cautious to remain within the narrative and not to go beyond it.

To answer your question I think a little "deductive" reasoning should be employed. Genesis 2:16-17, "And the Lord commanded the man, saying, "From any tree of the garden you may eat freely; vs17, but from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day the day that you eat from it you shall surely die."
At vs18, The Lord God says "It is not good for the man to be alone so He sets up man with a woman and tells him to name the animals which to me means Adam and Eve are to live or go on with their lives until they physically die.
This is backed up by the Apostle Paul at Romans 5:12-21. "Therefore, just as through one man sin entered into the world, and death through sin, and so death spread to all men, because all sinned-- Obviously the Apostle Paul is referring to physical. If you read the rest of the chapter Paul brings up the grace of our Lord Jesus Christ. Vs19, "For as through the one man's disobedience the many were made sinners, even so through the obedience of the One the many will be made righteous."
Paul concludes at Romans 5:21, "that, as sin reigned in death, even so grace might reign through the righteousness to eternal life through Jesus Christ our Lord." To me, it is extremely unlikely that our first parents were doomed to the lake of fire as one poster stated he could prove.

Adam and Eve will not be judged because they were already judged in the garden, judgment starts with Cain who was the first to commit murder and to the rest of humanity, and if Adam and Eve wont be judged then you know where they are!
The judgment at the garden of Eden was the first seat of judgment and Adam was punished  together with his wife, which other sin do you want them judged for which is not mentioned in scripture?
Their commandment was to eat of the fruit of all the trees in the graden save for the tree of knowledge of good and evil
Your commandment is to believe in Jesus as the only begotten Son of God, Adam was given one law, and he broke it and was judged immediately unlike Christians who wait to be judged after dying or after having a body transformation
Genesis 4:1

Now Adam knew his wife, Eve, and she became pregnant. When she gave birth to Cain, she said, “With the LORD’s help, I have produced a man!”

They then taught Cain and Abel about God  through an oral tradition. Abel must have learned from his parents that offering sacrifices is a way of pleasing God.
Adam is also a direct ancestor of Jesus and in the lineage of righteous people or the sons of God.
Luke 3:37

the son of Methuselah, the son of Enoch, the son of Jared, the son of Mahalaleel, the son of Cainan, the son of Enos, the son of Seth, the son of Adam, the son of God.

Scripture refers to Adam as a Son of God, so you know from this he will be in heaven together with his wife. They simply gain access as the first parents God created out of the mud, would God let Adam and his wife whom he created from the mud go to hell? I don't think so.
If Paul murdered Christians and later on repented, what of Adam who just ate a simple fruit? Adam is in heaven for he is the Father of all men. If the thief to the right of the cross repented and his whole life he stole what didn't belong to him and he is in paradise, what of our Father Adam? Is Adam not greater than this thief for:

Adam and Eve were the only mortals to eat of the tree of life
Adam was the first human being to name all the animals

Jesus has always forgiven men, even on the cross Jesus uttered the words Father forgive them for they know not what they do, Adam and Eve knew what they did as did Paul and the thief to the right but Jesus forgave all of them, even Adam and Eve.
Jesus said Abel is innocent and Abel is a saint, God commanded us to honor our parents in the ten commandments because Adam and Eve taught Abel about God, there is no shortcut to this because all of us knew about God because our parents took us to church. The parental authority is very important and that's why for this act of teaching Abel about God and sin, Adam and Eve are regarded as righteous.
God decides who goes to heaven and who doesn't, it is not sin or its power or the devil as it is written he shall show mercy to whoever he pleases, even mercy to go into life
Romans 9:15

“I will have mercy on whom I have mercy, and I will have compassion on whom I have compassion”.

God will show compassion and mercy to whomever be pleases and by the way judgment starts from Cain, Adam and Eve are exempted from judgment for Jesus said that all sin starting from the murder of innocent Abel(pay attention to where judgment starts) will be brought to book. Why didn't Jesus say, all sin starting with eating of the forbidden fruit?
Mathew 23:35

that all the innocent blood shed upon earth may come on you, from the blood of righteous Abel to the blood of Zechariah the son of Berechiah

Adam and Eve will not be judged because they were already judged in the garden, judgment starts with Cain who was the first to commit murder and to the rest of humanity, and if Adam and Eve wont be judged then you know where they are!
Context Change
The test to Adam and Eve was to not eat of the forbidden fruit and they broke this and were judged accordingly and their test was over and done with, Adam and Eve were judged in the garden for the law they broke.
Times have changed, now the command is to believe in Jesus as God's Only son and the punishment is not the same as Adam's, Adam's punishment for eating the fruit was banishment from the garden,toiling hard and death. Adam cannot believe in Jesus to be saved because you cannot believe in a figure that descended from you, he didn't even understand what God meant by the seed of the woman shall bruise the head of the serpent.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The effect of Adam and Eve's sin on them
Sin put man out of harmony with his Creator. It thereby damaged not only his relations with God but also his relations with the rest of God’s creation, including damage to man’s own self, to his mind, heart, and body. It brought consequences of enormous evil upon the human race.
The conduct of the human pair immediately revealed this disharmony. Their covering portions of their divinely made bodies and thereafter their attempting to hide themselves from God were clear evidences of the alienation that had taken place within their minds and hearts. (Genesis 3:7, 8)
Sin thus caused them to feel guilt, anxiety, insecurity, shame. This illustrates the point made by the apostle at Romans 2:15, that God’s law was ‘written on man’s heart’; hence a violation of that law now produced an internal upheaval within man, his conscience accusing him of wrongdoing. In effect God, responding to the man’s excuse for his changed attitude toward his heavenly Father, promptly inquired: “From the tree from which I commanded you not to eat have you eaten?” ​— Genesis 3:9-11.
To be true to Himself, as well as for the good of the rest of his universal family, God could not countenance such a sinful course, on the part of either his human creatures or the spirit son turned rebel. Maintaining his holiness, he justly imposed the sentence of death on them all. The human pair were then expelled from God’s garden in Eden, hence cut off from access to that other tree designated by God as “the tree of life.”​ — Genesis 3:14-24.
Were Adam and Eve set up to fail?
Regarding God’s creation, including the first humans on earth, the Genesis account says: “God saw everything he had made and, look! it was very good.” (Genesis 1:31) Adam and Eve were perfectly made, ideally suited to their earthly environment. There was nothing deficient in their makeup. Created “very good,” they were certainly capable of the good conduct that was required of them. They were created “in God’s image.” (Genesis 1:27) So they had the capacity to demonstrate to some degree the godly qualities of wisdom, loyal love, justice, and goodness. Reflecting such qualities would help them to make decisions that would benefit them and bring pleasure to their heavenly Father.
God endowed these perfect, intelligent creatures with free will. So they were by no means preprogrammed to please God​—like some sort of robot. Think about it. Which would mean more to you​—a gift that is given mechanically or one that comes from the heart? The answer is obvious. Likewise, if Adam and Eve had freely chosen to obey God, their obedience would have meant all the more to him. The capacity to choose enabled the first human pair to obey God out of love.​—Deuteronomy 30:19, 20.
Adam and Eve's sin - not an accident nor an unfortunate mishap
Since Adam and Eve were created perfect and since God’s command to them to not eat from the "tree of knowledge good and evil" was explicit and understood by both, it is evident that their sinning was willful and deliberate and therefore inexcusable. God’s words to them afterward offered no invitation to repent. (Genesis 3:16-24)
A footnote to Genesis 2:17 in The New Jerusalem Bible states that Adam and Eve laid claim “to complete moral independence by which man refuses to recognize his status as a created being . . . The first sin was an attack on God’s sovereignty.”
God’s law states that “the wages sin pays is death.” (Romans 6:​23) Rather than hide this law from Adam, God told him that the penalty for disobedience would be death. (Genesis 3:3) When Adam sinned, God, “who cannot lie,” kept his word. (Titus 1:2) Adam passed on to his descendants not only sin but also the wages of sin​—death.
Although sinful humans deserve the penalty of death, God extended to them “the riches of his undeserved kindness.” (Ephesians 1:7) His provision to redeem mankind​—sending Jesus as a perfect sacrifice​—was both profoundly just and supremely merciful. Being created in perfection and in ideal conditions was God's undeserved kindness given to Adam and Eve upon their creation as perfect humans under perfect conditions. They rejected this undeserved kindness by deliberately and willingly disobeying God, and thus forfeited any subsequent undeserved kindness that was given to their offspring through Jesus' perfect ransom sacrifice. It was profoundly just and loving by God to provide for this sacrifice for Adam and Eve’s offspring, as they were born into sin through no fault of their own.
Adam and Eve's response to their sin gives some further indication of their mental attitude towards the incident. “The woman whom you gave to be with me, she gave me fruit from the tree and so I ate,” said Adam (Adam blamed God for his own mistake). “The serpent​—it deceived me and so I ate,” responded Eve (Eve deflecting the blame for her mistake to the Serpent). Those words, spoken to God by our first human parents, marked the beginning of mankind’s long history of making excuses and avoiding accountability - both clear signs of feeling sorry for the consequences but not repenting from their own behavior that led to it.​—Genesis 3:12, 13.
In addition to that, being divinely commissioned and being the earthly head through whom God communicated instructions to the human family, Adam was God’s representative on earth. (Genesis 1:26, 28; 2:15-17; 1 Corinthians 11:3) Those serving in such capacity are said to ‘minister in God’s name’ and ‘speak in his name.’ (Deuteronomy 18:5, 18, 19; James 5:10) Thus, while his wife Eve had already profaned God’s name by her disobedience, Adam’s doing so was an especially reprehensible act of disrespect for the name he represented.​
They actually both committed thus —due to their status as perfectly created representatives of God, and the ideal conditions they were in— blasphemy against the holy spirit, of which Jesus said that such a sin would not be forgiven. (Matthew 12:31-32)

For it is impossible to restore again to repentance those who have
once been enlightened, and have tasted the heavenly gift, and have
shared in the Holy Spirit, and have tasted the goodness of the word
of God and the powers of the age to come, and then have fallen away,
since on their own they are crucifying again the Son of God and are
holding him up to contempt. (Hebrews 6:4-6 - NRSV)

Adam and Eve were created enlightened, they not only tasted but were able to indulge in the heavenly gift of dwelling with God more than any other human being (besides Jesus), they shared in the holy spirit, they experienced goodness which God will restore in the future. But despite all that, they have fallen away - it is impossible for them to be restored to repentance (not even "again" as they weren't in need of repentance before their sin - they were in a state that didn't need saving, but only sustaining, which is why the "tree of life" was in the garden of Eden, and they were separated from it).
What about the arguments of faith displayed by Adam and Eve after their sin?
Did God's covering of Adam and Eve by animal skin prove he had thereby covered their sin by slaughtering animals?
First: The bible doesn't say that God "slaughtered" animals to get their skin of. He is the creator - what would have held him from miraculously providing the skin without the need of slaughtering animals?
Second:

God is kind and considerate toward all, including “the unthankful
and wicked.” (Luke 6:35) For instance, God “makes his sun rise on
both the wicked and the good and makes it rain on both the righteous
and the unrighteous.” (Matt. 5:45) Hence, even those who do not
acknowledge God as their Creator still benefit from his kind
provisions for life and may enjoy a measure of happiness.
We find an outstanding example of kindness in what God did for
Adam and Eve. Shortly after they sinned, Adam and Eve “sewed fig
leaves together and made loin coverings for themselves.” However,
God knew that they would need suitable clothing in order to live
outside of Eden, where the ground was now cursed with “thorns and
thistles.” So God kindly responded to their need by making “long
garments from skins” for them.​—Gen. 3:7, 17, 18, 21.
Kindness - A quality expressed in word and action

Also the utterance of Eve when giving birth to Cain, apparently thanking the LORD (Genesis 4:1), doesn't prove Eve's repentance. Eve could validly say that Cain was produced “with the aid of the LORD” because God had not taken away the reproductive powers of sinful Adam and Eve and because, when passing judgment on her, God had said that she would “bring forth children,” though it would be with birth pangs.​— Genesis 3:16
Did Eve have in mind that she might be the foretold woman who would produce the seed by means of which deliverance would come? (Genesis 3:15) If so, she was greatly mistaken. (Revelation 12:1) Deliverance would come through Jesus - he is the seed. (Revelation 12:5,6) The serpent is Satan - called the "original serpent" in Revelation 12:9 and 20:2. Satan's/the Serpent's head would be "crushed" eventually by Jesus who would bring the Devil to "nothing" (Hebrews 2:14). I will not go into the full exegesis of Genesis 3:15 here, as it would make this answer much longer than it already is. It suffices to say that Genesis 3:15 has nothing to do with Eve!
"What about Cain and Abel - they offered a burnt sacrifice to God - they surely must have learned this from Adam and Eve!"
The bible doesn't show a single occurrence where Adam or Eve gave burnt offerings to God. How would Cain and Abel deduce that offerings would be a suitable gift to God then?
Think about this - Cain and Abel certainly had visibility on God's cherubim guarding the entrance to the Garden of Eden with a flaming sword. (Genesis 3:24) Furthermore, God remained in contact with the first humans and their offspring as He was interested in their survival and becoming many, as he still wanted them to "fill the earth" (Genesis 1:28) and also that true faith would be cultivated among humans because God "wishes all to know the truth... and to be saved" (1. Timothy 2:4)!
So Cain and Abel knew about their parent's sin and understood why they were outside of Eden. They must have had conversations with God. They must have understood that even though they were no longer perfect and would have to eventually face death, their lives were a gift from God.
Their offerings indicated a recognition of their alienated state and of their desire for God’s favor.
Ever wondered why Cain got aware that God liked Abel's burnt offering more than his? And why was Cain not surprised to hear God speaking to him? (Genesis 4:2) - I reckon that they conversed regularly.
So there is no explicit biblical proof that Adam and Eve did anything that would indicate their true repentance and faithfulness to the end of their lives.

I'm not saying that I have not missed something from the Bible - my interpretation is not infallible, nor am I the judge. But it looks to me that Adam and Eve have ended up in the lake of fire (Gehenna) based on the information available in the Bible.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
